could there be any unforeseen issues making changes so sudo is required to access pass command?
I rely heavily on the linux pass password utility for some fairly sensitive authentication details, and I decided to make the changes necessary so that I need to use sudo to run the pass command and view the contents of my user's .password-store dir.
The steps I took are:

chmod 770 /usr/bin/pass
chown root:user /usr/bin/pass
chown -R root:user /home/user/.password-store
chmod -R 700 root /home/user/.password-store
chown -R user:root /home/user/.gnupg
sudo ln -s /home/user/.password-store /root/.password-store
sudo ln -s /home/user/.gnupg /root/.gnupg

So things seem to work as intended. I need to sudo in order to run /usr/bin/pass and any of its options using user's gpg key, as well as to list the contents of the ~/.password-store dir.
But since I am no linux guru, I wonder if there is any chance this set-up opens me up to any potentailly unforseen (by me) security issues?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
